# Passing data to a vector within a while loop with ifstream

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop, ifstream

I'm working on an assignment for my C++ class, and having trouble passing data to a vector in a while loop using ifstream.

This is how i ended up doing it, which works, but is dependent on the data file being less than 100 integers:

```
void Frequency()
{
    ifstream frequency("test.dat");
    if (! frequency)
    {
        cout << "**Error opening File**";
    }
    else
    {
        int data;
        vector <int> numbers(101, 0);
        while(frequency >> data)
        {
            numbers[data-1] += 1;
        }
        for(int i = 100; i >= 1; i--) //
        {
            if (numbers[i] != 0)
            {
                cout << setw(3) << i+1 <<": " << numbers[i] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns the frequency of certain numbers in descending order.

This feels more like i'm beating my way through it than i'm coding, though (though my instructor insists "this is the easy way!" i don't want easy, i want right. I was doing it like this:

```
void Frequency()
{
    ifstream frequency("test.dat");
    if (! frequency)
    {
        cout << "**Error opening File**";
    }
    else
    {
        int size = 0;
        int x; //actually a useless variable, only exists so the program can iterate to find the size
        while (frequency >> x) //gives us the size of the data file
        {
            size++;
        }
        vector <int> numbers(size, 0);
        int data;
        int a = 0; 
        while (frequency >> data) //inputs the data into the vector
        {
            numbers[a] = data;
            a++;
        }
        for (int a = 0; a < size; a++)
        {
            frequency >> numbers[a];
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) //displays each subvector and it's value (for testing)
        {
            cout << "numbers[" << i << "]: " << numbers[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

But all of the vectors are returning as 0. Can anyone see why the data isn't passing through correctly?

This is the data file i'm passing, for reference.
     75  85   90  100
     60  90  100   85
     75  35   60   90
    100  90   90   90
     60  50   70   85
     75  90   90   70

EDIT: fixed some commented stuff. I'll definitely try doing it with MAP. The biggest thing that's confusing me right now (in the way that *I* did it is why the data file isn't passing into the vector)

Comment: I'd argue to the professor that the easiest way is a (hash) map.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't know how many distinct values are in your file you have two options: `resize` the vector if necessary, or use a `map`. The latter is the easiest way to tackle this problem:

```
std::map<unsigned, unsigned> numbers;

while(frequency >> data)
{
    numbers[data]++;
}
```

If you want to iterate through numbers again, you can *could* use your current approach. However, this will result in additional entries being added to your map (have a look at `std::map::operator[]`). However, you can use `iterators` to show only values that have been added to your map:

```
for(
    std::map<unsigned, unsigned>::iterator it = numbers.begin(); 
    it != numbers.end();
    it++
){    
    cout << setw(3) << it->first <<": " << it->second << endl;
}
```

If you are allowed to use C++11 it gets even simplier with range-for-loops:

```
for(auto entry : numbers){
{    
    cout << setw(3) << entry.first <<": " << entry.second << endl;
}
```